# How to merge feature branch on top of main?

Tags: git

I have a git workflow as the following:

```
Main: 

…. → ee68ee –> ff512e –> ed038c → fc08ef4 → a62847 → f0faf9e (HEAD)
    |
    |
    ee68ee → e994bd3 (HEAD)    --> Feature branch pull request
```

I want to merge my feature branch into main such that changes should be on top of main eg:

```
→ ee68ee –> ff512e –> ed038c → fc08ef4 → a62847 → f0faf9e → e994bd3(HEAD)
```

I did try git rebase but it is duplicating commit when I merge to main. Any ideas how can I achieve this.

Comment: Try to do an interactive rebase. You can then re-order your commits, putting your feature branch commit at the tip.

Comment: What specifically does "duplicating commit" mean? Git makes changes by making new history (making new conmits) and rehanging labels, it *cannot* alter existing history, this isn't an authority thing, it's a "because math" thing: it cannot be done.

Comment: What you show is not possible for two reasons: First, you cannot have 2 commits with the same hash. Secondly, if you change the parent of a commit, it must have a new hash. But if you are okay with creating new commits: rebase your feature branch onto main and you should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ee68ee` is the merge-base of main and your feature branch, **`git rebase main`** from your feature branch (or `git rebase main feature`) will create one new commit for the commit not reachable from main, putting the new location of the feature branch there (`e994bd3'`) with main (`f0faf9e`) as ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you are supposed to do a git rebase. Not git merge.
Follow the steps below for git rebase:

1. Checkout out and update the main branch

```
git checkout <main-branch>
git pull origin <main-branch>
```

2. The checkout the feature branch

`git checkout <feature-branch>`

3. Start rebase

`git rebase <main-branch>`

If there is any conflict between the main branch and feature branch, it will wait to fix it manually. Please respond for the messages which is printed when you run the git command.